# Session array unset and delete row

Tags: php, arrays, session, unset

I get the id of a product and try to delete from my session array.I use unset and everything goes well but when i try to display the data in a loop the session still have the deleted row so i get the error Undefined offset: 0.
I use a second session that just has the count of the first so when i delete one row it works fine.However when i try the same to the multidimensional session ($_SESSION['cart'] = $_SESSION['cart'] -1;) it doesnt work and i get the error Unsupported operand types..

So to sum up i need to delete a specific data from the session array and when i use unset it does delete it but the array still has all the indexes if i have 3 products i delete the second one and when i display them the array still have index 0,1,2..

Here is my code

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$c=$_SESSION['c'];

$id=$_GET['id'];


unset($_SESSION['c'][$id]);
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);


$_SESSION['c'] = $_SESSION['c'] -1;
$_SESSION['cart'] = $_SESSION['cart'] -1;
```

Comment: By the looks of things you're trying to subtract from an array a int. It doesn't make sense. As  `$_SESSION['c']` is in fact, an array and not an int(or float, or whatever).

Comment: i know i try actually to decrease the index of the array but dont know how.

Comment: Ah, well that's a whole different matter. Just do `$_SESSION['c'] = $_SESSION[VALUE YOU WANT GOES HERE].` So basically rewrite the index `c` of the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: well $_SESSION['c'] = $_SESSION['c'] -1; this line  works i m having issue  with this line  $_SESSION['cart'] = $_SESSION['cart'] -1;  the session array had 3 products and when i delete one of them the array still have 3 products but the one i unseted is empty so the array has 1 empty cell that i dont wont to be empty i just want to delete it so the 2 products will go 'up' and have the indexes 0 and 1.. does that make sense? sorry ..

Comment: So you want to change the array keys and sort them basically?

Comment: well yes for example if the array have the values 0,1,2 if the user deletes the value 1 the the array will have 0,2 right?What i want to do is when the user deletes the value 1 the array will have the values 0,1 something like going back.. i dont know if that is  possible but thats what im trying

Comment: Unset the values you want from `$_SESSON['c']`, loop thru it after than, create a new array with the values from `$_SESSON['c']` - example `foreach($_SESSON['c'] as $key => $value){$new_array[] = $value}`. After which replace `$_SESSON['c']` with the `$new_array`. It's the simplest thing I could come up with since `$_SESSON['c']` is of undetermined depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$_SESSION['c'] = $_SESSION['c'] -1;
```

by

```
$_SESSION['c'] = array_values($_SESSION['c']);
```

"-1" will throw error since you are trying to subtract numeric value from a N-dimensional array.
[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will return you updated $_SESSION['c'] after unset/delete operation is done.

P.S. Update your code accordingly for $_SESSION['cart'] as well.

Comment: $_SESSION['c'] = array_values($_SESSION['c']); solved the problem of mine, thank you so much